# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)\arcsin^2 x}{x^2} {\rm d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)\arcsin^2 x}{x^2} {\rm d}x.$$

Maybe, we can make a substitution $x=:\sin u, u\in [0,\pi/2]$. Then 
$$I=2\int_0^{{\pi}/2}\frac{u^2\cos u\ln\cos u}{\sin^2 u}{\rm d}u.$$
Can we go on from here?

Comment: Hint. $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x^2}\arctan^2(x)dx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 x^{2n}\arctan^2(x)dx.$$

Comment: WA says this here $$\frac{1}{18} \sqrt{\pi } \left(-\frac{18 \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{5}{4},\fr
   ac{5}{4};1\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-\frac{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \left(4 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{5}{4};\frac{7}{4},\fr
   ac{7}{4};1\right)+\log (512)\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}-9 \sqrt{\pi } \log
   (4)-\frac{36 \sqrt{2} \pi ^2}{\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}+\frac{36 \pi  \Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Why do you think it has a nice solution?